# Make background of QLabel png image transparent design time

Tags: c++, qt

I currently have a project with a Qlabel that has an image on it. The image is a png image and I have used it on other Qlabels in other projects and the background is always transparent however in this project the Qlabel has a white background. How can I make the background of Qlabel transparent during design time I am using QT4.

Answer (score 0):

if you have set the background color of your widget which is containing the label, the color is also set to cild widgets... set the background-color:"transparent"; and may add where you inizalize it  label->setStyle... or comparable. Sorry for adding this as answer but i can not make comments